# Django model relation

Tags: python, django

I'm making the model for my app and I have a question about the relationship of a model.

The Company model has one or more Offices.
And the Office has one or more Employees.

```
class Company(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        mail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
        NIF = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True, blank=True)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class Office(models.Model):
        company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Main')
        direction = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class Employee(models.Model):
        company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
        office = models.ForeignKey(Office)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        mail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name
```

How I can make a relationship between the employee and the company and office?

Comment: what you mean by "relate"? could you elaborate?

Comment: Do a relationship between the Employee and the Company and the Office.
The office belongs to a company
The employee belongs to an office of the same company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `company` foreign key from `Employee`.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

As the `Office` model already has a relationship with `Company` and `Employee` has relationship to `Office`, you can just access it like `employee.office.company` -

```
employee_one = Employee.objects.get(pk=1)
company_of_employee_one = employee_one.office.company
```

If you want to access the data other way around(i.e. get all offices of a company, get all employees of an office), you can do something like this -

```
company = Company.objects.get(pk=1)
offices = company.office_set.all()
for office in offices:
    employees = office.employee_set.all()
```